# How to display the activity last visited when click the icon on the desktop?

Tags: android, android-activity, icons

I configed the launcher activity in manifest file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hzxfkj.jxt" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.1" 
    android:installLocation="auto"> <!-- auto   internalOnly  preferExternal  -->

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="9" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <receiver android:name="com.hzxfkj.jxt.BootBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> 

        <service android:singleUser="true" android:name="com.hzxfkj.jxt.service.MessageService" android:label="jxtMessages"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.hzxfkj.jxt.MainActivity" android:theme="@style/activityTheme" android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.hzxfkj.jxt.MessageActivity"  android:theme="@style/activityTheme"  
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
        <activity android:name="com.hzxfkj.jxt.LoginActivity" android:theme="@style/activityTheme"  
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>

        <activity android:name="com.hzxfkj.jxt.MsgDetailActivity"  android:theme="@style/activityTheme"  
            android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true" android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>
        <activity android:name="com.hzxfkj.android.xflistview.XListViewActivity"  android:theme="@style/activityTheme" 
             android:launchMode="singleInstance"/>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

...

so when i click the desktop app icon, the MainActivity will start.
if i click the button on the MainActivity, the MessageActivity will be displayed.
then i click the "Home" key on the phone, the app will be hidden. but when i reopen the app by click the icon on the desktop, the app will display the MainActivity,not the last visited MessageActivity. 
how could it just show the activity page I last visited?

Comment: please, show your manifest file

Comment: y dont you add keep track of activity which is visited and on launcher activity u can redirect to respective activity?

Comment: use flag in every activity you open and put it in sharedpreferences so once you open your application it will check the value of your sharedpref and will redirect you to the right activity.

Answer (score 0):

don't use the singleInstance lanchMode.

delete `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

or change it to singleTask if need.

Comment: i seams to resolved the problem by delete android:launchMode="singleInstance". but a new problem is that:
my backgroud intent service checked a new message and notified on the status bar, when i click the notification icon. the MainActivity will not refresh and cannot display the new message in the listview:

Comment: @user2559787 do this problem happen when launcheMode is singleInstance?